# Universal cocos2d game to support iPad3

Tags: ipad, cocos2d-iphone, ios-universal-app

How would the image resources be named for the ipad & ipad HD versions in a universal app?

When supporting normal and HD images for iphone we use **imageName.png** & **imageName-hd.png**. But if I make an universal am I right in assuming that I would have to rename the images and use **imageNameiPad.png** & **imageNameiPad-hd.png**?

Please let me know how the naming convention works.

Thanks
Abhinav

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The correct way in **cocos2d** (version 2.0 or 1.1beta) is this:

**Normal iPhone:**

image.png

**Retina iPhone:**

image-hd.png

**Normal iPad:**

image-ipad.png

**Retina iPad:**

image-ipadhd.png

You must just call image.png in your code, then the code  will detect what device is and use the file properly.

Answer (score 4):

I beleive that it goes something like this:

**Normal iPhone:**

image.png

**Retina iPhone:**

image.png-hd

**Normal iPad:**

image.png-ipad

**Retina iPad:**

image.png-hd-ipad

**Do not use @2x instead of -hd because you will find that you will get some errors.**

Answer (score -1):

I guess that'll work exactly as you would name ressource to support retina display on iOS (for iPhone). Which to my mind is :

- MyFile.png is the standard resolution
- Myfile@2x.png is the resolution for retina display

Comment: but how would it differentiate between the one meant for iphone retina and the one meant for ipad retina?